# Display X rows sql using Php - 2D array

Tags: php, sql, multidimensional-array

```
<?php   //sql query which gets the data from database
$query = mysql_query ( "SELECT aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee FROM xyz"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row ($query);
?>
```

This query returns a 2-D array how to display that.
This returns a part of table.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
echo $row[3];
echo $row[4];
```

that's it. Or you can `print_r` whole array

```
print_r($row);
```

but to show all 5 lines you have in your DB, you should do it like

```
<?php 
$query = mysql_query ( "SELECT aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee FROM xyz"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_row ($query)){
         echo $row[0];
         echo $row[1];
         echo $row[2];
         echo $row[3];
         echo $row[4];
}
?>
```

Comment: there are several values of aaa,bbb,ccc

Comment: +1 for going to suggest `print_r()` you're ahead of me all day! leave some to me!! :P

Comment: @RikudoSennin: Lol. You're my enemy. I did 10k in 2 months. I can't allow you to be faster!!! (:p)

Comment: it returns 5 rows and 5 columns

Comment: :DD Actually I'm really taking my time here, but now that you said it, I MUST BE FASTER!! MADARA TIME SLOW ATTACK! `</insanity>`

Comment: @Techmax: no. it shows only 5 columns, one row. If you want to show 5 rows, I'll edit my answer

Comment: @RikudoSennin: It's about luck + I'll have school in 11 days, so I won't be active so much